# Issue with the Life Cycle flow execution with Fragment and Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

There is an Activity named **HomeActivity.**

A Fragment named **MyProfileFragment** is added inside fragment container.

Now, A **UserLocationFragment** is added on it.

Now, Inside UserLocationFragment, I am opening google place api dialog to select the particular address. I have override OnActivityResult method to set the result inside **UserLocationFragment**

**The Issue is :**

The MyProfileFragment's onResume() method is calling, After setting the address. means when I come to onActivityResult method which is override inside **UserLocationFragment**

What might be the issue ? or What I should do to avoid the calling of this previous Fragment's **onResume()** method named **MyProfileFragment** ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the code of  `MyProfileFragment` and `UserLocationFragment` ? It will help me understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MayurGajra Will you please check, I have added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it seems you're using an intent to launch the autocomplete activity. So according to the android lifecycle your `HomeActivity` is stopped when you move to `AutocompleteActivity` and so are it's child components i.e `Fragments` and when you come back and the `HomeActivity` is visible it resumes and so do the all the child `Fragments`. Hence, The onResume is called on the `MyProfileFragment` as well. We can not avoid this.

For this reason, I would not recommend making API calls on `onResume`.

But if it's your use case and you must do it inside `onResume` I would recommend having a Global `public static` variable in java or `companion object` variable in kotlin as a flag like you have commented  `isRefreshData` which gives you control when you should make API call. Make it `true` when you think it's right time and switch to `false` when you get the result.